# Nuget restore fails

Tags: macos, mono, nuget, nuget-package

We have a private nuget repository. It was working well until last Friday. Now we get the following message:

```
Error: TrustFailure (The authentication or decryption has failed.)
      The authentication or decryption has failed.
      The authentication or decryption has failed.
      Invalid certificate received from server. Error code: 0x5
```

What we tried to fix the problem:

- updated nuget.exe
- run the command `mozroots --import --machine --sync`